# Antenna sector power ratio (total power)

Tags: power, antenna, electromagnetism, summing

This is maybe a very basic question, which is driving me insane, because I can't remember the theory and neither I can seem to find any source about the topic.

I have an antenna, whose SPR (sector power ratio) is defined as the ratio between the co-polar field amplitude irradiated in a defined sector (let's say from -60° to +60° in respect to antenna's boresight), and the co-polar field amplitude irradiated outside of it plus the cr-polar field amplitude irradiated anywhere.

All the formulas I am finding simply reduce the problem to:

```
Sigma(Ampl Co in Sector) / [Sigma(Ampl Co out Sector) + Sigma(Ampl Cr everywhere)]
```

where Sigma is the sum of the amplitudes by each angular unit.

Now, the doubt that was raised to me was that since the two polarizations (+45° and -45°) lie with 90° angular difference from each other, they would lie on different vectorial planes too, therefore the sum shouldn't be the "normal" one.

Shouldn't the sum in this case be the **quadratic** sum? So basically:

```
Sigma(P Co in Sector) / Sqrt{[Sigma(P Co out Sector)]^2 + [Sigma(P Cr everywhere)]^2}
```

Is the following formula correct?

```
10*log{Sigma(P Co in Sector) / [Sigma(P Co out Sector)^2 + Sigma(P Cr everywhere)^2]}
```

Comment: 360 sphere/ cone angle of radiated power = antenna gain max. ( assuming impedance matched)

Comment: This is not quite what I was asking :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think about the properties of the `log`... Of course a `log(sqrt( ... ) )` is equal to `0.5 * log( ... )` therefore the formula was correct

Answer (score 1):

Powers add directly; signals like voltage or current have to add as \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\$ if they are un-harmonically related RMS values.

Electrical power is proportional to \$V^2\$ hence a normal "add" is appropriate. In other words, power is a scalar quantity and not a vector quantity.

Comment: Power is still a scalar quantity and does not add vectorially.

Comment: @Noldor130884 - you keep accepting then unaccepting this answer - what is troubling you?

Comment: sorry I saw this comment only now. Well, basically I'm not sure this really answers my question...